# The whole PC crashes after trying to start a virtual machine in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Yesterday I moved the iso files of my virtual machines and I didn't know that VMs will not work anymore.

I tried to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

After this, everytime I tried to start any virtual machine (tried even with new VM installed with good ISO file) my whole PC crashes and I must reset it hard. I use Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to remove everything about VirtualBox (even Virtualbox-dkms) and then install it again but the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you did?  For example, when moving the isos broke vb, why didn't you just move them back? What inspired you to install that package?  When you say you "tried" to run it, does that mean it didn't work?

Comment: First of all, I didn't know that moving the ISO files will create problems on opening a virtual machine (I realised this too late). After running the command, it returns the error:
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)
I ran it because I tried to repair the drivers

Comment: I suggest you try to fix that dpkg problem first; until you do, you can't install or remove any software to try to fix your vb problems.  There are many such questions on this site, try searching for a fix.

Comment: well, I solved the problem with the installation and now I can install aps without getting errors. After I reinstalled vbox-dkms the returned message was:

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.1+13-0ubuntu2) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.

But even with the complete reinstallation of virtualbox, the same thing happens.